# Combination problem question.

Tags: combinatorics

I am working on a combination problem and I need to check if I'm doing this right.

> There is a deck of cards that consist of 20 cards. There are four different colors, including 2 Green, 6 Yellow, 8 Black and 4 Red cards. Each colors are numbered, so they are distinguishable. If one draws 4 cards from this deck without replacement, how many different hands of 4 cards can one make given that exactly two cards are black ?

This is my claim.

Two cards are black, so there are 8*7 ways of having them.

The rest have to be non-black, so there are 12*11 ways of having them.

Since we don't care about the order of how we have the four cards, we divide the permutations by the number of order, namely, 4!.

So I think the ans is $\frac{8*7*12*11}{4!}$.

However, a book that contains this problem says that instead of dividing the bottom by 4!, it is divided by 4.

I think it is saying that there are 2! ways of ordering the black cards and 2! ways of ordering the non-black cards, but I don't think their claim is right, because it ignores the cases where Black-NonBlack-Black-NonBlack is treated as a different permutation.

Can someone confirm which argument is correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not **ordering** the cards, we are counting the number of pairs of black cards, and the number of pairs of non-black cards.

I would say that there are $\binom{8}{2}$ "tiny hands" of $2$ black cards, and $\binom{12}{2}$ tiny hands of $2$ non-black, fpr a total of $\binom{8}{2}\binom{12}{2}$ full hands of $4$.

Or else imagine picking the $2$ black cards in order from the black bunch. This can be done in $(8)(7)$ ways. But this double-counts each tiny hand of two black cards, so the actual number is $\frac{8\cdot 7}{2}$. A similar calculation can be made with the non-black.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It made it clear. So, it's just like a poker hand with full house.

Comment: You are welcome. One way to do a partial check on the correcness of an argument is to use much smaller numbers, where you can list and count explicitly. Unless you are quite unlucky in your choice of small numbers, if you have a wrong method it will give a wrong answer in a situation where you have full control of the counting.